# wowjs / animate.css and hidden elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

Elements on my page are hidden (using jquery's hide()), and revealed through users clicking on menu items (using jquery's show()).

The elements being shown from a hidden state are not playing wowjs or animate.css animations. If I remove the hidden state, and simply default them to showing, then the animations play on page load.

I'd like the animations to play when the element goes to a visible/shown state, not just when the user scrolls down to them (which I realize wowjs is meant for).

Comment: provide a code or fiddle please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow Js library not provide this facility like when click on element animation will apply,it's animation only apply when Element appear on DOM.You can apply animation when jquery show() is event accrued that time used JQuery addClass() function to provide animation on click event used addClass() function of JQuery:-

```
$("element").addClass("animation name from animate.css");
```